# Real time synch with external application on insert and update of frequently changing records

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, callout, largedatavolumes

In order to synch very large amount of frequently changing data to an external system, what will be best way to do it ?

We can't use trigger or schedule batches as these will fire so many times that system performance will be impacted.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a classic use case for [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) here.

> Receive near-real-time changes of Salesforce records, and synchronize corresponding records in an external data store. Change Data Capture publishes change events, which represent changes to Salesforce records. Changes include creation of a new record, updates to an existing record, deletion of a record, and undeletion of a record.

There are good resources both on [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) and [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/understand-change-data-capture) which can get you started in this direction.